# Reconstructing compiler arguments for precompiled-headers

Tags: compiler-construction, properties, cmake, precompiled-headers

I work with cmake 2.8.11 on Windows, generating makefiles for mingw-w64 in a Qt project.
I wanted to use precompiled headers. In order to do so, I need to recreate the arguments to the compiler. In the end I'm stuck with a hardcoded custom command:

```
foreach(dir ${Qt5Core_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Gui_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${Qt5Widgets_INCLUDE_DIRS})
    set(MY_INCLUDE_ARGS "${MY_INCLUDE_ARGS}" "-I${dir}")
endforeach()

add_custom_command(
    PRE_BUILD
    OUTPUT all.h.gch
    COMMAND
    ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} -x c++-header -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -std=c++11 -g
    -c "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/all_real.h" -o "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/all.h.gch"
    ${MY_INCLUDE_ARGS}
    DEPENDS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/all_real.h"
    IMPLICIT_DEPENDS CXX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/all_real.h"
    COMMENT "Generating precompiled headers"
)
```

It kind of works, but I should be able to use some variables to fill for all those -Ds and I shouldn't be needing the for loop or explicitly list the Qt modules.

I tried to read the target and directory properties, but they are empty!

```
find_package(Qt5Core)
find_package(Qt5Gui)
find_package(Qt5Widgets)
...
add_executable(app ${CPP_FILES} ${H_FILES} ${UI_FILES})
target_link_libraries(app Qt5::Core Qt5::Gui Qt5::Widgets)
qt5_wrap_ui(ui_main_window.h main_window.ui)
qt5_add_resources(app ${QRC_FILES})

GET_PROPERTY(dat1 DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
get_target_property(dat2 app INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
MESSAGE(STATUS "!!!! ${dat1}") # Empty!
MESSAGE(STATUS "!!!! ${dat2}") # Empty!
```

Also CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS contains only that what I put there myself by set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -H")
And I cannot really use that in add_custom_command as it is expanded along with the quotation marks.

Please help.